# Python - Append text to beginning and end of JSON

Tags: python, json

Ok this one's gonna be easy, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax. I am generating JSON elements via code, and I'd need to wrap some more info around them in as a JSON. I have the `output` JSON object. Officially, it's a `<class 'list'>`. What I was trying to do was:

```
outjson = "{"features": " + output + ", "crs": {"properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}, "type": "name"}, "type": "FeatureCollection"}"
```

(ofc the parentheses are not escaped, but this is just so you get what I'm trying to achieve). This ofc didn't work, because `output` is not a string. I've tried converting but I didn't succeed. What's the way to do this?

Comment: what didn't work with what you were trying to do? If you remove the outermost quotes from the string, you have a valid JSON object: `outjson = {
            "features": " + output + ", 
            "crs": {"properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}, "type": "name"}, 
            "type": "FeatureCollection"
            }`, that prints out as JSON: `{'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326'}}, 'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': ' + output + '}`, which of course is a `<type 'dict'>`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: No it's not. I actually want to do what you'd call string append if you were working with strings. I know that inside `output` I have a valid JSON  object (actually, a whole bunch of them), but I want the output file to have `"{"features": "` before listng stuff in `output` and `", "crs": {"properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}, "type": "name"}, "type": "FeatureCollection"}"` after.